# Does it make sense to use a ReaderWriterLock to detect disposal when a class is otherwise thread safe and lock-free?

Tags: .net, multithreading, dispose

Suppose I have a class that's thread safe, meaning any public instance methods are thread safe. The class is "lock-free" in the sense that I'm not explicitly using any locks within the code. There is a ConcurrentDictionary in use, which uses it's own locking, but from the standpoint of my own code, there are no locks in use.

The problem is "Disposal". Once disposal of my object begins, the lock-free code that accesses things like the ConcurrentDictionary or modifies Timer objects will crash with an unexpected exception if they, for example, check a _disposed flag, see that's its false, then carry on while another thread begins disposing the object. It would be a cop-out, I think, to just say that every method "except Dispose" is thread-safe. And I've seen people do that.

Ideally, Disposal should not proceed while any public instance methods are in use. Likewise, any public instance methods should not proceed while the object is being disposed or after its disposed. Any public method called after the object is disposed should throw a clear ObjectDisposedException.

**Do you think a good solution would be use a ReaderWriterLock, such that Dispose takes a "write" lock out, and all other methods take out a "read" lock?**

That way, under normal use, there is no lock contention (like there would be if I were to use a normal 'lock' statement), because all methods are just acquiring a read lock, and there's no limit on the number of simultaneous read locks. Since the code they're running inside the read locks is thread-safe, it's fine for them to execute concurrently within the read-locked sections. When the object is disposed, the write lock will ensure dispose runs by itself without any other code running within the read-locked sections and vice versa. Also, every time the "read" lock is acquired, the first thing it should do is check the "disposed" flag and throw an exception if the object has been disposed.

I just think this is a weird way to use a reader-writer lock, because it's protecting something so binary... all the code in the class is either unsafe to run or safe to run, because the object is either disposed or not disposed. But it seems to make sense to me. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: It does not.  You must only ever call Dispose() when no other code can be using the object.  Which inevitably implies that you never need a lock that protects against concurrency.  Using RWL could only ever hide a bug.  Disposal is optional, when it gets too hard to do it right then it is better to not do it.

Comment: @HansPassant But wouldn't the RWL actually make it easier to find such bugs, because it would ensure that a proper `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown, rather than something more unpredictable due to the internals being in an undefined state?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that "Disposed" is really a super-state an object as a whole can be in. So, in order for an object to be thread safe AND disposable, this pattern is necessary for any implementation to be correct. If a thread-safe object's methods can be called by any thread, and an object can be disposed by any thread, then that implies all methods should be wrapped in this kind of reader-writer lock.  Nito.AsyncEx actually has an AsyncReaderWriterLock that returns a Disposable to release locks. I wrapped that in a class that handles the  Read acquire lock, and auto-throws if disposed.

Comment: That AsyncEx library... it looks dubious. Not that it doesn't do what it says on the tin, but I wonder if that is something that should be done _at all_. `async`/`await` has always been about asynchronous IO, not thread synchronization. Does it even make sense to use it in this fashion? I'm not sure... but I'm also not sure it doesn't. Need to wrap my mind around this.

Comment: The point is, due to the nature of `async`/`await` you could end up with the same thread trying to acquire the lock _twice_. At this point, you're not granting the locks to _threads_ anymore, but rather to... not sure what to call them. Tasks maybe?

Comment: Then again, maybe it makes sense that way.

Comment: An alternate approach may be to implement an async Dispose method. I have an `IAsyncDisposable` abstraction, with this method: `void Dispose(Action<bool> onDisposed);`. The `bool` in the callback is true if invoked synchronously, false if async. This method will mark this object as disposed now; and check if any async actions are currently running: if so, then your callback will be cached, and it will be invoked when the actions return.

Comment: Do you actually need to synchronize this? The ConcurrentDictionary does not even implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8) is the best option here.

The problem isn't starting an operation while disposal is in progress. That's the easy part and can be solved simply by using [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=netframework-4.8). The hard part is not starting the disposal while an operation is in progress. And for that you need your operations to take some kind of a lock while they're executing. The `ReaderWriterLockSlim` fits the requirements perfectly.

Comment: Would that pose a conflict as the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is protecting the call to `Dispose()` (or, as you say, protecting all non-`Dispose()` calls), meanwhile that same `ReaderWriterLockSlim` would itself need to be `Dispose()`ed _during_ the call to `Dispose()`?  Or would that just have to be left for the garbage collector to clean up?

Comment: @BACON Hmm, good catch! Let's see... Yeah, I guess that's the only scenario I can think of that is truly safe.

Comment: The lock would have to be left for garbage collection. It would necessarily have to exist at least until the finalizer if one exists) for the owning object runs.

Comment: The cool thing is, if you use Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncReaderWriterLock, you can use "using" statements to acquire and release the lock. And if you wrap that in a class with methods "WhileNotDisposed" and "DisposeWithinLock(Action disposeAction)", then you can implements methods that all just do this `using (_disposable.WhileNotDisposed()) { method logic }`, then method logic always runs within the read lock, WhileNotDisposed handles acquiring the read lock and throwing an ObjectDisposedException (releasing the lock in a finally block) automatically if the object is disposed.

Comment: The wrapper itself keeps the _disposed boolean, which is sets the first time you call `_disposable.DisposeWithinLock(() => { cleanup logic });`, and if called more than once just returns safely without calling cleanup logic (assumed to have already run), so it enforces good practice of allowing Dispose to be called multiple times, in a thread-safe manner, without repeating logic or throwing exceptions.  It's actually scary to think of how much code is out there that doesn't perform all these necessary checks and just cops out and says Dispose is not thread safe, haha.

Comment: Incidentally, the finalizer is really the only place that can guarantee the object is no longer in use. By definition, the managed application should not be concerned with tracking how many references there still are to an object.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question only indirectly, but in order to use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, I'm afraid you have to leave them dangling.

If you peruse the source code, [ReaderWriterLockSlim.Dispose(bool)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs.html#aec40428c4f68a0a), you'll find the following:

```
if (WaitingReadCount > 0 || WaitingUpgradeCount > 0 || WaitingWriteCount > 0)
    throw new SynchronizationLockException(SR.GetString(SR.SynchronizationLockException_IncorrectDispose));
 
if (IsReadLockHeld || IsUpgradeableReadLockHeld || IsWriteLockHeld)
    throw new SynchronizationLockException(SR.GetString(SR.SynchronizationLockException_IncorrectDispose));
```

It is not possible to dispose the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` while any threads are waiting for or using the lock.

To add insult to injury, it also appears that `ReaderWriterLockSlim.Dispose(bool)` itself is not threadsafe.

After reading through the comments here, and a bit of thought, I've produced this:

```
using System; //ObjectDisposedException
using System.Threading; //Interlocked, SpinWait
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; //[CallingMemberName],[CallingLineNumber]
/// <summary>
/// A lock similar to ReaderWriterLockSlim with the distinctions that it's intrinsically supportive of re-entrant locks (because threads aren't tracked)
/// and that there is only one, non-repeatable writer.
/// <para/> This is designed to satisfy the need to dispose a multi-threaded object in a thread-safe way.
/// </summary>
public class DisposalLock
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal representation of disposal state. Akin to bDisposed
    /// </summary>
    int disposalState = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Counter of how many disposal-sensitive work blocks are currently in execution.
    /// Also serves as a waitable indicator in <see cref="FlagDisposal"/>
    /// </summary>
    long busyCount = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to generate the <see cref="ObjectDisposedException"/> when work is attempted after disposal has begun.
    /// </summary>
    string objectName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of <see cref="DisposalLock"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_instance"></param>
    public DisposalLock(object _instance)
    {
        objectName = _instance.GetType().Name;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Register that a disposal-sensitive work block has started.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_callingMember"></param>
    /// <param name="_callingLine"></param>
    public void StartWork([CallerMemberName] string _callingMember = default,
                [CallerLineNumber] int _callingLine = default)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref busyCount);
        if (DisposalStarted) 
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref busyCount);
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(string.Format("{0} [{1}:{2}].", objectName, _callingMember, _callingLine.ToString())); 
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register that a disposal-sensitive work block has ended.
    /// </summary>
    public void EndWork()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref busyCount);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to notify that Disposal has started. Causes all requests for StartWork() to throw an ObjectDisposed exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool FlagDisposal()
    {
        //Store the disposal state for this thread.
        int myInitialState = disposalState;
        //If disposal state was non-zero, someone else already started (or even finished) disposal, nothing to do.
        if (myInitialState != 0) { return false; }

        //else, if we read disposalState as 0, let's try to change it from a 0 to a 1
        if (myInitialState != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref disposalState, 1, 0))
        {
            //If we end up here, then another thread managed to modify disposalState first. We'll let them handle it.
            return false;
        }

        //If we get to here, we are the disposing thread! Wait until all other work is complete.
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(delegate { return busyCount == 0; });

        //Signal that disposal can safely proceed.
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to give a boolean response indicating whether disposal-senstive work should be started.
    /// </summary>
    public bool DisposalStarted => disposalState != 0;
}
```

Fundamentally, you instantiate it with your class constructor, passing your instance in for exception traceability.
Then you use it the same as a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`:

```
disposalLock.StartWork()
try { DoWork(); }
finally { disposalLock.EndWork();}
```

```
private void Dispose(bool _bDisposing)
{
    if(!disposalLock.FlagDisposal()){ return; } //same as check for already disposed
    if(_bDisposing)
    {
        DoDisposalStuff();
    }
    //clean up unmanaged assets.
}
```

The major difference (as displayed) is `StartWork()` throws an `ObjectDisposedException` and you can only "WriteLock" one time (just like disposal).
Of course, DoDisposalStuff() can't be "work" else you'll just get an exception.